# Prometheus and HDInsight Integration

Tags: prometheus, grafana, azure-hdinsight, timescaledb, telemetry

Recently I am working on a new Telemetry design where plenty of microservices should be monitored for performance, maintenance, and other reasons.

The monitoring of microservices can be archived using the EcoSystem of TimescaleDB, Prometheus, and Grafana, while there are many charts like timescale\tobs that are offering this ecosystem out-of-the-box.

[image]

But in the case of the Bussiness Central (SAAS), while this is hosted on Microsoft, the telemetry metrics are on HDInsight without access to the underlying infrastructure.

[image]

I am looking at how HDInsight metrics can be integrated into Prometheus, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much idea about Azure HDInsight, but seeing [monitoring on Azure HDinsights](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/monitoring-on-hdinsight-part-1-an-overview/) I see Ambari as the recommended tool. There is an Prometheus Ambari exporter provided by Microsoft [here](https://github.com/microsoft/AmbariBasedHadoopExporter), which you can scrape using Prometheus and remote-write into TimescaleDB using [Promscale](https://www.timescale.com/promscale).

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: In Business Central Application you do not have access to the underlying resources, so I am not sure how any Prometheus exporter can be deployed.

Comment: Does Ambari expose any REST API?